# Could "An active PHP session" cause 504 errors?

Tags: php, cpu-usage

My Nginx dedicated server with 4 CPU cores and 16GM which should have more than enough resources keeps crashing (with 504 errors) due to limits related to CPU and PHP child processes.
I am trying to look for the cause. I have the following warning in Wordpress: A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests.

Could this be causing the 504 errors?

Comment: start by uninstalling all the installed plugins. Then load the site. Then install each plugin one by one, and you will find what plugin is consuming all the CPU resources.

Answer (score 0):

A REST API should be stateless. There is no use for a session in that case.
It is difficult without further information.
A 504 (timeout) could happen if PHP tries to start a session in background without proper configs for e.g. Redis, in which a custom session handler can store a session.
use

```php
phpinfo();
```

to find your PHP logs and other settings. Post it here. You also can use shell to see the configuration.

```
php -i
# or
php -i | grep log
# or 
php -i | grep session
```

Be aware most systems run different PHP settings for cli & web requests.
Have a look with `top` or `htop`, which are system tools which process results in high CPU, Memory usage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).